# Unable to load a specific webpage on Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am unable to see the following webpage in an Android webview: https://play.ericsson.net It should re-direct to a login page, can anyone produce a success case for opening the above webpage in an android webview?

FYI I'm activating javascript and setting WebViewClient.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this? Https sites are troublesome on android.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had come across it somewhere else too but there was a comment that it defeats the security purpose but I do start seeing the webpage now

Comment: @2cupsOfTech Have you tried going to http://play.ericsson.net/ rather than https in the WebView? It looks like it redirects to the same page. It seemed to work for me and I don't think you want to do this with the actual login page because this will nullify the SSL security.

Comment: @dcharms did you try play.ericsson.net from an android webview? doesn't work for me

Comment: To be exact, it's because certificate issuer isn't on android's trusted list probably. So you can ignore this error. I'd consider catching specific one though, using error variable in this overriden method.